How do I securely pass a secret to a Java app?
I'm assuming that an attacker has root access, but I want to keep a keystore safe. So, in this context, the secret is the keystore key, and 'securely' means:

The secret shouldn't appear in plaintext in a disk file (root can read it)
The secret shouldn't be passed in an environment variable (root can read it)
The secret shouldn't be passed on the command line (anyone can read it)

An encrypted secret doesn't appear to be of any value, since the Java app must then be told how to decrypt it, so it needs to be securely given a second secret.
I'm actually running Alfresco and Solr, and the only options appear to be the command-line, property files, and envvars. I'm running both these apps from systemd services and, in both cases, a shell script is called, and the script eventually execs Java.
I can get the secret securely from the web front-end into the shell script, simply by writing it into a FIFO/named pipe, and then reading it out in the script. At this point, the secret is known to the script, but I still have to pass it to Java somehow. Can anyone suggest how to do this, preferably without modifying the Java source code? I don't (yet) write Java, but presumably there's some way to read the pipe from bash directly? Or is there an easier way to do this?

If someone has root access, what's stopping them from just reading the memory of your program and extracting the key, regardless of how you pass the key to your program? If it's encrypted in memory, they can just breakpoint a function that uses the key.

@ipodtouch0218: that assumes that the attacker is ready and waiting when a user wants to start the service, and has installed a debugger on a headless server. In practice, the service is started once, and remains on for a long time, and the secret is only available for a second or two when the service is started. We can also detect when the server has been compromised. In the most realistic scenario the attacker has a few hours to check ps and /proc/pid and to search for disk files.

Physical security is the answer to this. Access to the secure room via security card.

Adding a second secret that allows the application to decrypt a file will also serve the attacker - so that is no real option.
Something that is also not too safe but at least gives visibility might be a password safe on the network. The application would have to connect using credentials that the attacker can take over. But it would retrieve a one time password - and the vault software would write the password access into the logs and rotate the password - both for the application server as well as on the system that the password is meant for.
Now if you find a password access in the logs and the timestamp matches one of the application server startups everything is fine. If the timestamp does not match an application startup and the application looses access because the password was rotated something is fishy.
